# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a streaming video for a project, I am creating in node.js including html, and I can not finish by this error
`Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'getContext' of null`

then I need to fix that problem, but I can not because I sought solutions and this type of error, but none works for me up to work only issue
I had to comment on these lines:

```
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.width = 800;
        canvas.height = 600;

        context.width = canvas.width;
        context.height = canvas.height
```

Here the codes of my proyect:
        
    
    
        
        Emitir Video

```
    <canvas style = "display:none;" id "preview" width='1280' height='720'></canvas>

    <div id = "logger"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("preview");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // This is the line that generates the error

        canvas.width = 800;
        canvas.height = 600;

        context.width = canvas.width;
        context.height = canvas.height;

        var video = document.getElementById("video");
        var socket = io();

        function logger(msg)
        {
            $("#logger").text(msg);
        }

        function loadCam(stream)
        {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            logger('Camara cargada correctamente [OK]');
        }

        function loadFail()
        {
            logger('Camara no conectada, Favor Conectela');
        }

        function  viewVideo(video,context)
        {
            context.drawImage(video,0,0,context.width,context.height);
            socket.emit('stream',canvas.toDataURL('image/webp'));
        }

        $(function(){
            navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msgGetUserMedia);

            if (navigator.getUserMedia)
            {
                navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, loadCam, loadFail);
            }
            //1000 = 1 Seg.

            setInterval(function(){
                viewVideo(video,context);
            },70);

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks i will apreciate helps.

Comment: There's several typos, for instance the equal sign is missing in `<canvas ... id "preview"` so the element is not found, hence `null`

Comment: You forgot a `=`  at  `id "preview"`. As of that there is not element with the id `preview` in the DOM and `document.getElementById("preview")` returns null. Beside that the question is not related to `node.js`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mistyped `id` attribute. `id "preview"` should be `id="preview"`

Comment: OOOMGGG THANKS, JUST A = MAKE ME STUPID JAJAJA, THANKS A LOT NOW IS WORKING YEAHHH

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `id "preview"` to `id="preview"`, then you can move on to whatever the next error will be :)